# Scala Parser Combinator: recursion

Tags: scala, parsing

I am writing a parser for boolean expressions, and try to parse input like `"true and false"`

```
def boolExpression: Parser[BoolExpression] = boolLiteral | andExpression 
def andExpression: Parser[AndExpression] = (boolExpression ~ "and" ~ boolExpression) ^^ {
            case b1 ~ "and" ~ b2 => AndExpression(b1, b2)
}
def boolLiteral: Parser[BoolLiteral] = ("true" | "false") ^^ {
            s => BoolLiteral(java.lang.Boolean.valueOf(s))
}
```

The above code does not parse `"true and false"`, since it reads only `"true"` and applies rule `boolLiteral` immediately

But if I change the rule `boolExpression` to this:

```
def boolExpression: Parser[BoolExpression] = andExpression | boolLiteral
```

Then, when parsing `"true and false"`, the code throws a StackoverflowError due to endless recursion

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Parser.boolExpression(NewParser.scala:58)
    at Parser.andExpression(NewParser.scala:62)
    at Parser.boolExpression(NewParser.scala:58)
    at Parser.andExpression(NewParser.scala:62)
    ...
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The core of the issue is that the usual parser combinator libraries use parsing algorithms that don't support [left recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion). One solution is to rewrite the grammar without left recursion, meaning that every parser needs to consume at least some input before invoking itself recursively. For instance, your grammar can be written like so:

```
def boolExpression: Parser[BoolExpression] = andExpression | boolLiteral

def andExpression: Parser[AndExpression] = (boolLiteral ~ "and" ~ boolExpression) ^^ {
  case b1 ~ "and" ~ b2 => AndExpression(b1, b2)
}
```

But you can also use a parser combinator library that's based on another parsing algorithm that supports left recursion. I'm only aware of one for Scala:
https://github.com/djspiewak/gll-combinators
I don't know to what degree it is production ready.

//edit:
I think this one might also support left recursion. Again, I don't know the degree to which it is production ready.
https://github.com/djspiewak/parseback

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be parsing a string of boolean constants separated by "and" which is best done using the `chainl1` primitive in the parser. This process a chain of operations `a op b op c op d` using left-to-right precedence.

It might look something like this totally untested code:

```
trait BoolExpression
case class BoolLiteral(value: Boolean) extends BoolExpression
case class AndExpression(l: BoolExpression, r: BoolExpression) extends BoolExpression

def boolLiteral: Parser[BoolLiteral] =
   ("true" | "false") ^^ { s => BoolLiteral(java.lang.Boolean.valueOf(s)) }

def andExpression: Parser[(BoolExpression, BoolExpression) => BoolExpression] =
  "and" ^^ { _ => (l: BoolExpression, r: BoolExpression) => AndExpression(l, r) }

def boolExpression: Parser[BoolExpression] =
  chainl1(boolLiteral, andExpression) ^^ { expr => expr }
```

Presumably the requirement is more complex than this, but the `chainl1` parser is a good starting point.